# IT компании для стажировки.

Tags: c#, работа, c++

Хочу пройти стажировку в более менее серьёзной компании, так как это будет полезно для профессионального роста, в большинстве требуются выпускники Высших учебных заведений, к коим я не отношусь. Сам самоучка, пишу в основном на С# в Unity3D так же изучал C++ и пытаюсь практиковать его работая с OpenGL. Имею опыт программирование около двух лет. Так же разрабатывал системы на PHP, в общем могу адаптироваться под технологии, имею слабую математическую базу, но думаю засесть за укрепление когда появятся конкретные задачи. Прошу что нибудь посоветовать, хотел пробиться на лето в Яндекс, как раз думал к началу подтянуть мат базу, но туда только с вышкой берут, что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Ищешь вакансии на джуниор разработчиков и рассылаешь своё резюме ) Выхлоп приглашений на собеседование должен быть примерно 50%. Т.е. отослал резюме в 5 мест, 2-3 конторы пригласили на собеседование.

Comment: Фигесе выхлоп, 50%! Хорошо если 5% приходящих хоть на junior стажтровщиком сгодятся :)

Comment: Так то я про приглашение на собеседование, если нормальное резюме и у конторы реально есть вакансия на джуна, то где-то в половине случаев и пригласят.
А приглашение на стажировку/работу понятно, что будет не больше 10% в среднем )

Comment: @junior_dev, а тестовые задания? На них хороший отсев же, ещё до собеседования.

Comment: @klopp, ну да, возможно. Мне кажется, что тестовые задания это просто как тест на серьезность и адекватность, если человек ничего в ответ не прислал, то знач не очень то ему нужна эта работа, а если прислал чето, то даже не особо вдаваясь в решение могут сразу на собеседование пригласить. А ТС вроде как серьезно настроен и даж какой-то опыт есть, думаю тестовое задание не составит для него проблем.
А ваще, да, наверно я погорячился что в среднем 50% приглашений на собес.

Comment: Дык в том-то и дело, что настроены все серьёзно... А вот стандартные тесты на код и алгоритмы проходят не все. Типичное и дурацкое (в общем-то) построение всех перестановок элементов массива - уже хороший критерий :)

Comment: @klopp я что-то не понял, что значит "построение всех перестановок элементов массива", сдвинуть все элементы массива, например 1-й становится 2-м, последний - первым и т. д., или как? Напишите плз чуть подробнее условие )

Comment: Дан массив. Тип элементов значения не имеет. Напишите алгоритм перебора всех перестановок элементов этого массива. 

Просто же, и без привязки к языку :) В любом случае человек с хорошей базой любому языку обучится быстро.

Но если нужны знания языка/среды/протоколов - тут другие вопросы. Тоже простые, но очень хорошо отсекающие.

Comment: А что, взяли мы пару лет назад молодого, на стажировку. Причем и не искали стажера, но была вакансия (дыра) в отделе девелопмента, но те, кто в теме, на ЗП предложенную идти не хотели. Стажер через год дослужился до полноценного девелопера и до сих пор кодит у меня в конторе. Для его холостяцких 22-х лет ЗП больше чем куда-либо. Но оговорюсь: взяли его благодаря его целеустремленности и харизме, что немаловажно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Хочу пройти стажировку в более менее серьёзной компании

пишу в основном на С# в Unity3D

 так же изучал C++ и пытаюсь практиковать его работая с OpenGL.

 Так же разрабатывал системы на PHP
```

нечего конкретного? большие компании любят узкоспециализированых программистов (особенно аутсорсовые), любят опыт работы над БОЛЬШИМИ проектами, не любят стажировать (вообще что это такое?? это когда студентов берут на свои курсы(туда тоже есть конкурс обычно), учат, а потом по результатам экзамена могут взять взять к себе).

А вообще пробуй уже сейчас ходить на все собесы что предлогают, нечего страшного его не подойдешь сразу, будешь знать их стэк вопросов, к чему стремится..

Comment: Уже работал в одной компании C# программистом, проработал два месяца и уволили из-за конфликтов с начальством.Работа не нравилась, я был одним программистом и был предоставлен сам себе, так что не каких более смышлёных товарищей не было. Так же не получал почти не какого опыта. Специализация геймдевелопинг.

Comment: в геймдевелопинге вообще любят на готовые проекты(это если мы про казуалки и аркады, а не работу на крайтек)

Comment: >ответ: длина массива в степени "кол-во эл-тов словаря массива"

Кол за невнимательность к заданию, следующий.

Comment: @HolyMonkey, а чего вы ждали? Что у вас будут интересные задачи, решению которых вас будет обучать куча терпеливых и более опытных программистов?

Кстати количество получаемого опыта, далеко не в последнюю очередь, зависит именно от вас, а не от конторы.

Откровенно говоря не верю в то, что работая в геймдеве( если это конечно правда ), даже за 2 месяца, вы не получили никакого опыта и, даже если так оно и есть, то, ИМХО, виноваты в этом только вы и никто другой.

Comment: @klopp, мне очень стыдно, поспешил =(

Comment: Ладно каюсь, полезный опыт был, когда писал рантайм импортёр .obj . А так большинство задач были очень типичными, и я понимаю что впереди рутины ещё больше. Просто хотел поднабраться опыта и знаний на менее ответственной работе.

Comment: так тебе наоборот надо не в большие компании, а в мелкие, большим компаниям не нужны новички (хотя и для мелкий компаний, это дорогое удовольствие), у них нету "нетривальных" задач, им надо что бы ты пришел и "писал код, бл#"

Comment: @AlexWindHope, @Gorets

По мне так джуниор - это человек, хорошо подкованный в принципе, но желающий набраться опыта в какой-то области. А вовсе не начинающий программист, которого все будут водить за ручку. Могу привести ещё стандартный вопрос, про C: "read() вернула 0, ваши действия?" Реакция должна быть мгновенной, и чем ближе к стандарту, тем лучше :)

Comment: Да я и не против писать код если честно, пока что нахожу это очень даже увлекательным. Судя потому, что Read() должна возвращать линк на поток, то стоит выбросить ексепшин. Хотя не уверен, но вы меня заинтриговали, что стоит делать? :)

Comment: @klopp, я бы проверил errno.

Comment: @mikillskegg, не-а :) Зачем? Ошибки же нет.

Comment: @klopp Я не знаю Си, но подозреваю, что read() возвращает 0 когда доходит до конца строки, соответственно нужно прекратить её считывать, когда он вернул 0. Не правильно?